# What are the odds that American household have a rice cooker?

Tags: rice, cookware, sushi, japanese-cuisine, rice-cooker

We started [a Kickstarter project](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1256265752/sushi-ninja-a-complete-guide-to-making-sushi-with?ref=home_location) of creating an e-book with online videos to show you how to make sushi, from a master sushi chef.

We are wondering what the odds are that an American family has a rice cooker. We are thinking of adding a section in the book to teach people how to cook rice using their pans, to save them money from buying rice cookers.

Comment: Surely your actual question is: "what are the odds that an American *who would buy a book about making sushi* has a rice cooker or would be willing to buy one?"

Comment: An informal survey of (engineer) coworkers yielded the following data: 5 out of 7 coworkers have a rice cooker. Of the two who didn't, one is single and eats only instant rice, the other is me who already knows how to cook rice in a pot so I didn't replace my cooker when it broke.

Comment: Sobachatina : wow.  I've worked in places where you're lucky if 2 out of 7 even knew how to cook, much less had a rice cooker.  At once place, 3 of 6 of the employees lived in a home with a rice cooker, but as 3 of shared an apartment, if you went by homes it was only 1 of 4 had one.

Comment: Hmm, "this question will likely solicit...polling"?

Comment: @Joe- Having a rice cooker doesn't imply cooking ability. Those coworkers that had one did so because they weren't confident cooking rice without it.

Comment: For the record, I didn't actually vote to close this - I think it's quite possible to answer without being a poll. (I removed the "do you have one?" bit that was originally there.) I just thought it was funny that it actually directly caused people to take polls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most American households don't have rice cookers - it's just not part of traditional American kitchens. Most Asian-American households probably do. Some reasonable fraction of people likely to make sushi do - but probably not all.

But this seems beside the point. Cooking rice in a pot is simple, and won't take a significant amount of work to explain. Why not just do it?

Comment: Maybe you are right!